# JavaFX How set ImageView from SceneBuilder

Tags: java, javafx

As i see in `SceneBuilder` you can set graphic for `ImageView` (though that image will not work if you export the project as **.jar** and you have the image into the jar).

1)**I want to** set images for some fxml buttons through `SceneBuilder` but i can't find anything about that.

2)**Also** it will be usefull if you provide info on how to do with `.fxml` what i do with `getClass().getResource("image.png");`,so i have not to do this on the java file manually.

> **Edit:**

Both answers from **Fabian** and are **John Vernee** are correct each one for question 1 and 2 but i can choose only one.

The structure of resources folder:

[image]

Comment: You say the "image will not work if you export the project as a `.jar`", but I don't think that is the case.  Can you provide an FXML file and an output of `jar tvf` on a jar file which is broken in this way?

Comment: I can tell you the "also" part. And I've built a test jar that runs fine with the image in there, by setting it from FXML.

Comment: @jewelsea i dont know how to set it from fxml.I have setted it from SceneBuilder and the image has to be out of the jar.Thats what i mean.How can i set it to be inside the jar and work again?

Comment: @Jorn Vernee how you done that?I am asking for that.

Comment: Ok I'll write an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SceneBuilder drag the `graphic` node you want to use (in this case `ImageView`) from the *Library* to the `Button` in the *Hierarchy* view. Drop it there and you should see the `graphic` node displayed as a child of the `Button`.

This will result in a fxml like this

```xml
...
<Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button">
    <graphic>
        <ImageView fitHeight="150.0" fitWidth="200.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" />
    </graphic>
</Button>
...
```

By using the gear button next to the image property of the `ImageView` you can specify a image url starting with `@` by selecting *Switch to document relative path*. Input `image.png` for the url `@image.png`. Saving the fxml to the correct location relative to the image will display the image in SceneBuilder.

Comment: one more think..It is working though the fitHeight and fitWidth has to be changed to 0 for the image to keep its original width.What is the difference between document relative path and classpath relative path?

Comment: @GoXr3Plus: `fitHeight` and `fitWidth` are not necessary, if the image should keep it's original size. Document relative path (starts with `@` in the fxml) is relative to the location of the fxml, classpath relative is usually relative to the "package root" (starting with `/` in the fxml). Some information about that should be contained somewhere in this document: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html

Answer (score 1):

You can set the  url for an `ImageView` in FXML like this:

```
<ImageView>
    <image>
        <Image url="@my_image.png" />
    </image>
</ImageView>
```

It will look in the same folder as the FXML file for the image.

---

You could set the graphic of a `Button` by referencing it from FXML:

```
<!-- Define some ImageView -->
<fx:define>
    <ImageView fx:id="my_image">
        <image>
            <Image url="@my_image.png" />
        </image>
    </ImageView>
</fx:define>

<!-- Reference it here -->
<Button graphic="$my_image"/>
```

---

I'm building my jar using [apache maven](https://maven.apache.org/)'s plugin for eclipse, using the `javafx-jar-plugin`.

If you've worked with maven before, you can use this plugin in `pom.xml`:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>8.5.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>application.MainFXML</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

---

I've put the FXML file and the image in the same folder under `src/main/resources`, so they get included into the jar.

Run maven build with the `jfx:jar` goal.

Comment: Can i set the image for a button via SceneBuilder?2)I have some images in a source folder named resources/images .When i export the file as jar how it has to be written into fxml?Like this (image ="@resources/images/image.png" ?

Comment: @GoXr3Plus I couldn't find it in SceneBuilder, but I got it to work in FXML :) I updated the answer.

Comment: @GoXr3Plus About how to write it, with ```@``` it will start looking in the same folder as the FXML file. So you need a _relative path_. e.g.; if your FXML file is in ```resources/fxml/my_fxml.fxml``` and the image in ```resources/images/my_image.png```, then you should write ```@../images/my_image.png```.

Comment: Something more i want to ask is,the ../ will work only for windows?

Comment: @GoXr3Plus Windows uses ```\```, but Java mostly uses ```/``` which is what unix uses too, and it should work on both. I'm not 100% sure, but I think the ```..``` is universal.