# Resizing treeview icon

Tags: java, treeview

It's a simple Javafx program code with an intention to have an icon in front of 
each node of tree view. The problem I face, I get way too bigger icon. How can I resize it to have same icon with all nodes?

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeView;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;

@FXML
TreeView<String> treeview;
@FXML
Image icon = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/image/folder.png"));

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {

    TreeItem<String> root = new TreeItem<>("root", new ImageView(icon));
    TreeItem<String> nodeA = new TreeItem<>("Node A", new ImageView(icon));
    TreeItem<String> nodeB = new TreeItem<>("Node B", new ImageView(icon));
    TreeItem<String> nodeC = new TreeItem<>("Node C", new ImageView(icon));
    TreeItem<String> nodeD = new TreeItem<>("Node D", new ImageView(icon));
    TreeItem<String> nodeA1 = new TreeItem<>("A1", new ImageView(icon));
    TreeItem<String> nodeA2 = new TreeItem<>("A2", new ImageView(icon));
    TreeItem<String> nodeB1 = new TreeItem<>("B1", new ImageView(icon));
    TreeItem<String> nodeB2 = new TreeItem<>("B2", new ImageView(icon));
    TreeItem<String> nodeC1 = new TreeItem<>("C1", new ImageView(icon));
    TreeItem<String> nodeD1 = new TreeItem<>("D1", new ImageView(icon));
    treeview.setRoot(root);
    root.getChildren().addAll(nodeA, nodeB, nodeC, nodeD);
    nodeA.getChildren().addAll(nodeA1, nodeA2);
    nodeB.getChildren().addAll(nodeB1, nodeB2);
    nodeC.getChildren().addAll(nodeC1);
    nodeD.getChildren().addAll(nodeD1);``

}
```

Comment: what are the dimensions of 'folder.png' image?What dimensions you get running the program?

Comment: Dimensions were 250x250 so that was the problem. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the comment:

~~>You can resize your image without resizing the actual file image:

```
// resizes the image to have width and height of 100 while preserving the ratio and using
 // higher quality filtering method; this ImageView is also cached to 
// improve performance

ImageView iv2 =newImageView();     iv2.setImage(image);
iv2.setFitHeight(100);  iv2.setFitWidth(100);  iv2.setPreserveRatio(true); iv2.setSmooth(true); iv2.setCache(true);
```

> ~~>Also a better way is to add the [ImageView](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/ImageView.html) directly from the
> [SceneBuilder](http://gluonhq.com/labs/scene-builder/) into the fxml:
>
> [JavaFX How set ImageView from SceneBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38213366/how-to-setgraphic-from-javafx-scenebuilder)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
ImageView img=new ImageView(icon);
img.setFitHeight(20);
img.setFitWidth(20);
TreeItem<String> root= new TreeItem<>("Root",img);
```