# JavaFx: how make a clickable image using scenebuilder

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, desktop-application, scenebuilder

I wanted to know how to make clickable image using ImageView which takes me to another FXML using scene builder. I am using eclipse IDE.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've never used scene builder, but you can just call `setOnMouseClicked(EventHandler<MouseEvent> event)` on the `ImageView` object.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ImageClickExample extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        ImageView img = new ImageView("https://i.stack.imgur.com/oURrw.png");
        img.setPickOnBounds(true); // allows click on transparent areas
        img.setOnMouseClicked((MouseEvent e) -> {
            System.out.println("Clicked!"); // change functionality
        });
        Scene scene = new Scene(new StackPane(img));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Image Click Example");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.sizeToScene();
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

---

**1**)Create a `Button` or (`Label` ) in `SceneBuilder`

**2**)Add an `ImageView` to the Button using `SceneBuilder`

Relevant question:[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38213366/javafx-how-set-imageview-from-scenebuilder)

**3**)Use CSS:

[image]

```
    1)Inside the `SceneBuilder` or

    2)Using an external css file(with styleclass or with css id) as shown above i have added all the three ways(choose one :) ):

  .crazyButton{
      -fx-background-color:transparent;
      -fx-border-color:transparent;
      -fx-text-fill:transparent;    
  }

  or


  #myButton{
     -fx-background-color:transparent;
     -fx-border-color:transparent;
     -fx-text-fill:transparent;    
  }
```

Here you can play with the method `setPickOnBounds(true/false);` if you want the transparent areas of the `Button` to receive click events.

**4**)Add an `ActionListener` or `MouseListener` to the `Button` using `SceneBuilder` or plain `Java Code`

---

Answer (score 1):

Lets start with scenebuilder, open the fxml file. Drag-and-drop ImageView from Scenebuilder library(right panel). Once added, select the ImageView and give it a fx:id "iView" in this case, then goto Code section and add a function name in OnMouseClicked field. I named my function "LoginUser".

: [image]

Now open the controller file in eclipse IDE.

define the function with @FXML tag:

```
@FXML
private boolean LoginUser() throws ClassNotFoundException {
    Stage mainStage = (Stage) iView.getScene().getWindow();

    try {
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("file.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            mainStage.setScene(scene);
            mainStage.setTitle("Test Window");
        }
            catch(Exception e){}
}
```

Load the fxml file you want to on image click.